# Probability greatest roll of z dice exceeding greatest roll of h dice?

Tags: probability, dice

Let's assume there are two players in a dice game; zombie and hero.

The Zombie rolls *z* fair 6-sided dice.

The Hero rolles *h* fair 6-sided dice.

If the heroes greatest dice roll is larger than the zombie's greatest dice roll, the hero wins.  Otherwise, the zombie wins.

How can I calculate the probability of the hero winning as a function of *z* and *h* (without just enumerating the answers).

Example 1:
z = 1,
h = 2

Zombie rolls (4), hero rolls (1,5).  Hero has a higher dice roll and wins.

Example 2:
z = 2,
h = 2

Zombie rolls (4,4), hero rolls (1,4).  Hero does not have a higher dice roll and loses.

Related Question: [Given a die, what is the probability that the second roll of a die will be less than the first roll?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/given-a-die-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-roll-of-a-die-will-be-less)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $Z$ denote the greatest dice roll of Zombie and $H$ the greatest dice roll of Hero. Assume Zombie's rolls and Hero's rolls are independent

Then $\mathrm P(Z\leqslant n)=(n/6)^z$ for every $1\leqslant n\leqslant 6$ hence $\mathrm P(Z= n)=(n/6)^z-((n-1)/6)^z$. Likewise, $\mathrm P(H\leqslant n)=(n/6)^h$ hence $\mathrm P(H\gt n)=1-(n/6)^h$ for every $1\leqslant n\leqslant 6$. This yields
$$
\mathrm P(H\gt Z)=\sum_{n=1}^6\mathrm P(Z=n)\mathrm P(H\gt n)=\sum_{n=1}^6((n/6)^z-((n-1)/6)^z(1-(n/6)^h),
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm P(H\gt Z)=1-\frac1{6^{z+h}}\sum_{n=1}^6(n^z-(n-1)^z)n^h.
$$

Comment: The RHS of your final equation should begin with $1$, not $6^{−h}$.

Comment: @Byron: Indeed it should. Thanks.