# IF I roll 2 different value dice what is the probability that the first will have a higher value than the second

Tags: probability, dice

This is a follow on to a [similar question about 2 rolls of the same die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/given-a-die-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-roll-of-a-die-will-be-less).  I'm not sure how to extend any of the numeric answers there to comparing two different sized dice if they're too large to make the one graphic solution feasible. ex a D61 and a D245

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a simple example, say a d4 versus a d7. Here's a chart from the link to the other question that you provided, adapted for the different dice:

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
 &1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ \hline
1&=&<&<&<&<&<&< \\
2&>&=&<&<&<&<&< \\
3&>&>&=&<&<&<&< \\
4&>&>&>&=&<&<&<
\end{array}

There are $4\cdot7 = 28$ possible outcomes, of which $4$ are draws, $6$ are when the d4 wins, and the rest when the d7 wins. Note that it is easier to calculate the number of "<" in the diagram than the ">", because the "<" form a triangle.

To generalise this, suppose that your dice have $m$ and $n$ sides, with $m < n$. Then there will be $m$ draws; the d$m$ will beat the d$n$ $m \choose 2$ times, and the rest of the time, the d$n$ will win.

In other words, the chance of a tie is
$$\frac{m}{mn}=\frac1n,$$
the chance of the d$m$ winning is
$$\frac{m \choose 2}{mn} = \frac{\frac{m(m-1)}2}{mn} = \frac{m-1}{2n},$$
and the chance of the d$n$ winning is
$$1 - \frac1n - \frac{m-1}{2n} = \frac{2n-m-1}{2n}.$$