# Odds there is a higher number rolled than you in N amount of trials?

Tags: probability

So, I'm not the strongest with probability and I'm a bit confused how to approach this problem.

Let's say I have to roll a number from $1$ to $99$. How would I calculate the probability of someone rolling higher than the number I have just rolled, within $N$ rolls?

As an example:

> There are $15$ people in a group, including me. Each person rolls once. I roll a $85$. What is the odds of someone else getting $> 85$?

I have read through this [Q & A.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/given-a-die-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-roll-of-a-die-will-be-less) But I'm not sure how to extend this to my use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean strictly higher, there are $14$ rolls that beat yours, so the chance a given roll will not beat you is $\frac{85}{99}$.  The chance that $N$ rolls in a row do not beat you is $(\frac{85}{99})^N$.  The chance that at least one of them beats you is then $1-(\frac{85}{99})^N$.

Comment: Yes, I mean strictly higher.

Comment: Also I apologize, but I meant from 1-99. Does that affect anything?

Comment: It changes the chance that one roll beats yours to $\frac {14}{99}$  Can you follow through the argument with that?

Comment: Okay so. If I understand the concept. 1 roll beats mine at 14/99 chance. Hence the chance that none of the rolls beat me is.. 1-(85/99)^N. If there are 14 other people then it would be. 1-(85/99)^14 = 88.17% any of them don't beat me? Is that right? It seems... kinda high?

Comment: Are we sure we have to subtract that number from 1?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "The chance that at least one of them beats you is $1-0.85^N$"? It was brought up in chat by the OP. I just want to confirm that I wasn't wrong.

Comment: The subtraction from $1$ gives the chance that at least one beats you.  I had confused myself and have fixed it

Comment: Accepted! Thank you!